# What is the differnece betwwen Full and Major garbage Collection in Java garbage

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have recently started digging into Java Garbage Collection and gone through a lot of articles on it. But a question that I have not been able to find an answer to is, regarding the difference between Full and Major Garbage Collection. 
Following things that I understand:
 
Minor GC happens in the Young Generation space
Major GC happens in the Old Generation space
But When and where does the Full GC happen, and what exactly is it?

Comment: @StephenC the linked answer does not correctly answer this question in the face of G1. Hell, it's not even correct for CMS.

Comment: I linked to a Question.  If the Answers are inaccurate / out of date, feel free to add more accurate / up to date ones.  The point is that the Question is a duplicate.

Comment: Since SO has no mechanism of replacing the accepted answer once it becomes outdated I see little point in answering the old question.

Comment: @SpencerC the linked answer does not clarify the difference between Full and Major GC. I was specifically interested in Major-Full differences. I found an article, https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc, which does mention <br>
<b>
This leads us to the point where instead of worrying whether the GC is called Major or Full GC, you should focus to finding out whether the GC at hand stopped all the application threads or was it able to progress concurrently with the application threads.
This confusion is even built right into the JVM standard tools.
</b>

Comment: You may want to expand on your question then to include further details you're interested in.